# Retrieve specific values of instance variable from each object of a list containing Objects of different classes

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, java-7

I have a list which contains objects of different classes say A, B, C, D, E, F, G. Each of the objects(A, B, C, D, E, F, G) have an instance variable "name" in it. I want to iterate over the list and retrieve values stored in each of those object's name variable.

I tried below code

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Object obj: list_containing_different_objects) {
      str.add(obj.name) or  str.add(obj.getName());
}
```

But `obj.name` will give error as I don't know the exact index(as it can be different each time) in the `list_containing_different_objects` where A,B,C,D,E,F are stored. Also If I know the index, I couldn't fathom any solution for it.Can someone help me out of it?

Comment: By "different objects" you mean "objects of different classes"?

Comment: yes..object of different classes. Edited the question to reflect the same

Comment: Do the different classes share any superclass? Can you tell us which is the error you are getting? Thanks.

Comment: no , they don't.

Comment: This may be a poor design. I would suggest that you look up "liskov substitution principle". In my career, I've never seen a good reason to have a list of objects without anything in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Reflection**

Assuming the classes do not share a common base class or interface which contains the method you may use Reflection to invoke the method.  There is a lot of error handling to make it work properly but the following example waves that away and forces the caller to deal with it.

```
public String getName(Object named)
throws NoSuchMethodException, 
       SecurityException,
       IllegalAccessException,
       IllegalArgumentException,
       InvocationTargetException
{
  Method method = named.getClass().getMethod("getName");
  return (String) method.invoke(named);
}
```

The following iterates a List of objects and invokes the above method.  Since the Exceptions are percolating up, this method has to handle them.  You could just catch Exception here but I left the full list for completeness.

```
public void printNames(List<Object> namedObjects) {
  for (Object obj : namedObjects) {
    try  {
      System.out.println(getName(obj));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException |
             SecurityException |
             IllegalAccessException |
             IllegalArgumentException |
             InvocationTargetException e) {
      System.err.println("Failed to invoke getName on object - skipping");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether the classes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` and `G` have a common base class or interface.

#### Common base type

If not, you could, for example, create an interface like this:

```java
interface Nameable {
    String getName();
}
```

and then make each of the classes implement this interface. Then you can easily just call the `getName()` method on each of the objects:

```java
for (Nameable nameable : listContainingDifferentObjects) {
    str.add(nameable.getName());
}
```

#### `instanceof`

Otherwise, if the classes will not or cannot implement a common interface or extend a base class, then the classes are **unrelated**, despite having a field with the same name.

In that case, you end up having to check each type, cast it and use the field<sup>1</sup>:

```java
for (Nameable nameable : listContainingDifferentObjects) {
    if (obj instanceof A) {
        str.add(((A) obj).name);
    }
    else if (obj instanceof B) {
        str.add(((B) obj).name);
    }
    // et cetera
}
```

If your classes don't implement a common type, but still have a field with the same name, I would rethink the design.

#### Reflection

vsfDawg came up with using reflection to dynamically invoke the `getName()` method or access the `name` field. While one *could* indeed make it work, you should avoid to use it if that's possible, and only use it if there's no other way. [➤ More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26424561/507738)

---

<sup>1</sup> Since version 16, Java supports *pattern matching*, which simplifies the ceremony of checking type, casting and using the value. For instance:

```java
for (Object obj : listContainingDifferentObjects) {
    if (obj instanceof A a) {
        str.add(a.name());
    }
    else if (obj instanceof B b) {
        str.add(b.name());
    }
    // et cetera
}
```

See [this article](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/amber/pattern-match.html) for more details.

Comment: yes, my classes don't implement a common type, but still have a field with the same name

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.But I think , I don't have any other way except Reflection to resolve this issue

Comment: @user2755407 Well, if you must...

Answer (score 0):

I like 'MC Emperor's answer about common base class, it's the way to go.
However, if you do not have that common class and cannot change the code.
Reflection can be used to achieve what is needed.

The code below does not even need a getter (getName()), it just needs a 'name' field.

```
class A {
    public A(String aName) {
        name = aName;
    }

    public String name;
}

class B {
    public B(String aName) {
        name = aName;
    }

    public String name;
}

class C {
    public C(String aName) {
        name = aName;
    }

    public String name;
}

@Test
public void testClasses() {
    List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
    List<? extends Object> list_containing_different_objects = Lists.list(new A("a"), new B("b"),
            new C("c"), new A("aa"));
    
    for (Object commonObj : list_containing_different_objects) {
        try {
            Field field = commonObj.getClass().getField("name");
            String nameValue = (String) field.get(commonObj);

            str.add(nameValue);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // print the results
    str.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The result of this test execution looks the following:

```
 a
 b
 c
 aa
```

I hope this was helpful.